# Scale animation slower than 1px per frame

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to use a scale filter with values changed for each frame.

```
ffmpeg  -y -f lavfi -i "color=#FFFFFF:size=1280x720" -loop 1 -i black.png          -filter_complex "[1]scale=-1:'ih+n/5':eval=frame[obj];[0][obj]overlay=430:259"   -t 5 final.mp4
```

And as soon as object height changes faster than 1px per frame it looks pretty good. But if I want the animation to be slower (ih+n/5), the animation looks bouncing, like object height changes once per 5 frames: [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpOML.gif)

How to fix this?

Comment: If you mean "choppy", it's because of the rate of change. You may then want to look at the `minperpolate` filter.

Answer (score 0):

You may create larger image and scale down the output.

The following example is at 1Hz for testing.

- Set the input to 5 times the resolution - 6400x3600 instead of 1280x720.
- Down-sample the output to 1280x720.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "color=#FFFFFF:size=6400x3600:rate=1" -loop 1 -i black.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=-1:'ih*5+n':eval=frame[obj];[0][obj]overlay=2150:1295,scale=-1:720" -t 30 final.mp4
```

---

Animation:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying this as well. But the problem is still there. In your animation, the box is resized not for each frame but once per 5 frames, which doesn't give enough softness :(

Comment: I can't see it... Even with `ih*5+n`?

Comment: yes, just tried your command and got https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ErxY0Ov_DY2fqvYTPlPA7S-S0kUUtOHW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks OK, for 1Hz video. Modify `rate=1` to `rate=25` for getting smooth result.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rotem! This is exactly what I need. Didn't know that rate can affect like this.